# Copy message without URL(Link) pyrogram

Tags: message, pyrogram

How to delete any link (text_link, url) from message that i want to copy (copy_message function)?

I imagine it like this:
We have original message from some telegram channel
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qITpN.png)
And I want to copy this message to my telegram channel, BUT remove (delete) the link
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rQ7tD.png)

in the end

Answer (score 0):

You can copy the message and then change the caption to anything you want. Here is the piece of code for that.

```
@app.on_message()
def my_handler(client, message):
 
    copy = message.copy(receiving_chat_id)
    copy.edit('Anything you want to change the caption of the images')
```